# Keep everything in sync

Tags: reactjs

I have a list of users coming from the database

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
database.getUsers.then(users => setUsers(users))
```

I print that in a simple list and when I click on each of them I render a form to update the name

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});
database.getUser(userId).then(user => setUser(user))

useEffect(() => {

    // I need to implement debounce or something like that here. any suggestions are welcome;)
    database.saveUser(userId, user).then(user => console.log(user.name + 'saved!'))

}, [user])

<input value={ user.name } onChange={(e) => setUser({...user, name: e.target.value})} />
```

My question is: how to keep **users** updated with the name I just updated in one particular **user**?

Answer (score 1):

for your problem it is better to code like this :

```
const [user, setUser] = useState({});


useEffect(() => {
   fetchUserInfo()
}, [])

const fetchUserInfo = () => {
  database.getUser(userId).then(user => setUser(user))
}

const changeHandler = e => {

    setUser({...user, name: e.target.value});
    database.saveUser(userId, user).then(user => console.log(user.name + 'saved!'))

}

<input value={ user.name } onChange={changeHandler}/>
```

in this way while you typing your username your db will be sync with your form.

Comment: yes your right , i was forget about it
thanks to mention it

Answer (score 0):

let say you have some unique id  `user_id` in your user list each individual user object.

```
database.saveUser(userId, user).then(user => {

    const updatedUsers = users.map(function(userInfo){
        if(userInfo.user_id === user.user_id){
            userInfo.name = user.name;
        }
        return userInfo;;
    })
    // update the userlist with current updated user
    setUsers(updatedUsers)
    console.log(user.name + 'saved!')
})
```

Comment: I like this. how to make it work if lists is in one component and detail is in another component?

Comment: you can use useReducers in parent component